# Problems connecting ASP.NET MVC3 website to MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm having problems connecting my website (asp.net mvc3) to MySQL.

Localhost is working, but on the server I receive the following error:

> **Error:** Unable to locate the Data Provider. Requested Net Framework. Maybe it is not installed.
>
> **Stacktrace:** [ArgumentException: The repository provider specified is not found in the configuration or is not valid.]
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetFactory(String
>   providerString) +11468668
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(String
>   newConnectionString) +575
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.TryInitializeFromAppConfig(String
>   name, AppConfig config) +144    ...
>   +21    System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
>   +44    System.Linq.Queryable.Where(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate) +85    AcusticoA3.Controllers.HomeController.Index() +978
>   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +79
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +264
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +39
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12()
>   +124    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter
>   filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
>   +727142    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor,
>   IDictionary`2 parameters) +309
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName) +727076
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +159
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
>   +334    System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClassb.b*_5() +62    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass1.b*_0() +15
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClasse.b*_d() +52
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +606    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288

I'm using Mysql.connector 6.6.5.0 and EntityFramework 5.0.

My connectionstring:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model.csdl|res://*/Models.Model.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=[HOST];user id=[USER]; password=[PASSWORD]; database=[DATABASE]&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>   </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Can you post the implementation for `MySql.Data.MySqlClient`? And maybe try `provider=System.Data.SqlClient` instead?

Comment: "Unable to locate the Data Provide" likely means MySQL provider is not installed on the server, no?

Comment: Hi, this my code:

using(var db = new MyEntities()){
    // The error is happening here.
    ViewBag.BookData = (from t in db.book where t.Date >= currentData select t).Take(2);
}

Comment: The provider is installed on server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved.

Just put the provider dlls in the bin folder and do the setting in Web.config:

```
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <clear />
      <remove invariant="MySQL Data Provider"/>
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.6.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />     
    </DbProviderFactories>   </system.data>
```

Just remember to change the provider version.

Answer (score 0):

You can also tell the compiler to copy these files in the bin directory, by setting **"Copy Local"** to **True**:

[image]